# Sumar elementos contenidos en un diccionario Python

Tags: python

Necesito crear un diccionario que tenga la suma de elementos de otro diccionario, de la forma más eficiente computacionalmente hablando.

El diccionario principal es de la forma:

```
{'11': [0.76700000000000002, 3455.0, 0.76700000000000002, 0.76700000000000002, 34.0, 0.76700000000000002], '22': [34.0, 0.76700000000000002]}
```

Necesito crear un nuevo diccionario que contenga las mismas claves pero con la suma de los enteros del primer dicionario. La salida entonces sería:

```
{'11': [3458], '22': [34.767]}
```

Comment: Hola Jorge!¿Qué es lo que has intentado? Muestranoslo junto a la explicacion de el error que te da, o el resultado que te sale, para poder ayudarte. Un saludo

Comment: Jorge, la idea es que lo intentes primero por tu lado y nos muestres tu esfuerzo y tu problema si es que no lo pudieras resolver. Te podríamos dar muchas soluciones pero al no mostrar lo que has hecho podríamos entender que estás buscando alguien que lo haga por ti.

Comment: Además, la suma de los elementos de `11` es 3492, no 3458.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si quieres crear un nuevo diccionario (no hacer la suma sobre el que ya tienes) lo más simple y eficiente puede ser usar diccionarios por compresión junto a la función preconstruida [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#sum):

```
d = {'11': [0.76700000000000002, 3455.0, 0.76700000000000002,
            0.76700000000000002, 34.0, 0.76700000000000002],
     '22': [34.0, 0.76700000000000002]}
```

- En Python 3:

  ```
  r = {key: [sum(value)] for key, value in d.items()}
  ```
- En Python 2:

  ```
  r = {key: [sum(value)] for key, value in d.iteritems()}
  ```

La salida es:

> {'11': [3492.0679999999993], '22': [34.767]}

La razón de usar `dict.iteritems` en Python 2 se debe a que `dict.items` retorna una lista de tuplas clave/valor en esta versión, pudiendo resultar en un problema de memoria y eficiencia con diccionarios extensos. `iteritems` retorna un iterador. En Python 3, `dict.items` retorna un [**view object**](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views), el cual es iterable.

---

Si deseas evitar en lo posible los errores de precisión ocasionadas por las sumas intermedias y su representación en punto flotante, puedes usar [`math.fsum`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/math.html#math.fsum):

- Python 3:

  ```
  import math

  r = {key: [math.fsum(value)] for key, value in d.items()}
  ```
- Python 2:

  ```
  import math

  r = {key: [math.fsum(value)] for key, value in d.iteritems()}
  ```

Salida:

> {'11': [3492.068], '22': [34.767]}

---

Dado que estas creando una lista con un solo elemento, si no vas a usar esa lista posteriormente, crea las claves con la suma solamente:

```
r = {key: math.fsum(value) for key, value in d.items()}
```

Salida:

> {'11': 3492.068, '22': 34.767}

Comment: Si bien la respuesta es cojonuda, es una pena que se contesten preguntas planteadas sin mostrar ningún tipo de esfuerzo.

Comment: un 1+ por la respuesta, hace tiempo que trabajo con python y jamás había visto tanta genialidad en tan pocas lineas de código.

Answer (score 1):

lo que tienes que hacer es recorrer el diccionario y en cada elemento recorrer la lista y sumarla

```
main_dic = {'11': [0.7670, 3455, 0.767, 0.767, 34.0, 0.767], '22': [34.0, 0.767]}
dic_result = {}
for key, value in main_dic.items(): # iterar los item del diccionario
    suma = 0 # variable donde se guardará la suma de los elementos
    for v in value: # iterar los elementos
        suma += v # sumar los elementos y guardarlos
    dic_result[key] = suma # añadir al nuevo diccionario la misma llave con la suma de los elementos
```

o si prefieres esto en una función:

```
    def suma_valores_dic(main_dic):
        dic_result = {}
        for key, value in main_dic.items():
            suma = 0
            for v in value:
                suma += v
            dic_result[key] = suma
        return dic_result
```

después es solo llamar la función:

```
diccionario = {'11': [0.7670, 3455, 0.767, 0.767, 34.0, 0.767], '22': [34.0, 0.767]}
resultado = suma_valores_dic(diccionario)
print(resultado)
```

para más información sobre la utilización de los diccionarios he encontrado algunas documentaciones que te pueden servir:

1. https://jarroba.com/diccionario-python-ejemplos/
2. http://librosweb.es/libro/algoritmos_python/capitulo_9/utilizando_diccionarios_en_python.html
   sobre todo en [librosweb](http://librosweb.es/), ahí hay mucha información que te puede servir. También su sesión de [Python para principiantes](http://librosweb.es/libro/python/)